# Layer transparency in GIMP

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

When you create a layer in Photoshop you can create a new layer and select the transparency when you do it. How does one go about doing this same thing in GIMP? I've seen other answers about adding transparency to an image but what I need is a transparent black png to use as a background for a webpage. So in short I need to know how to create a black image where I adjust the about of transparency - say 80%. Is there an easy/quick way to do this equivalent to photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the foreground-color to black.

[image: screenshot foreground-color]

2. Create a new File and expand the "advanced Options" and select "Foreground-Color" in the "Fill with" - Dropdown.
3. Create a new tranparent layer by selecting "Transparency" in the Layer Fill Type.

[image]

4. Move the background-layer (the black one) above the transparent one and enter 80% in the transparency-control.

[image]

5. Click File->export as and select "PNG Image (*.png)" in the bottom right dropdown.
6. Keep all settings as default in the next window and click "Export".

Comment: Fab thanks - I didn't have the Layers toolbox open so that fixed it!